# Performing search opertaion while using chrome but not in firefox(Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

This is the code snippet for chroome:

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search"]').send_keys("kao")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]').click()
```

The browser automatically opens Youtube and searches for the passed string[which is the task I intend to do]

The main problem appears when i start using firefox.The page loads properly.I am basically using the same code but every time I run it, it throws the following error:

```
Message: Element <g id="search"> is not reachable
```

I cannot pass any string to the search bar or even click it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Xpath is not correct. It's Unable to locate search field and buttton

You can use this one

```
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='search']").send_keys("kao")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='search-icon-legacy']").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight error in the xpath `//*[@id='search']` that it returns two elements as in below screen. The reason being the `*` in the above xpath acts as a wild card and matches the other `ytd-searchbox<id="search">` tag in the page. The same is true for `//*[@id="search-icon-legacy"]`.

So you must try changing to the xpath like below to locate the web elements uniquely

```
//input[@id='search']
//button[@id='search-icon-legacy']
```

Errored Xpath:

[image]

Comment: I got it.Thanks for the explanation